# change a list from a dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have a problem in changing each element in a list to create another list from the dictionary(problem start from line 17)

```
    from itertools import combinations
a={'X_1=2':0.897,'X_2=3)':0.892,'X_2=2':0.965,'X_3=3':0.905,'X_3=2':0.953,'X_4=2':0.863}
# the list is formed as [X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4]
y1= [1,3,4,5]
y2= [0,3,5,9]
y3= [0,2,6,4]
y4= [1,0,1,2]
Full_List = [y1,y2,y3,y4]
temp=[]
convert=[]
for r in range(2,5,1):
    Combinations = combinations(Full_List, r)
    print("Finding maximum for a combination size of %d"%r)
    for eachCombination in Combinations:
        print("Finding combination for tuples ", *eachCombination)
        temp=list(map(max,zip(*eachCombination)))
        for z in range(0,5):            # converting the final list to right number from the dictionary
            if temp[z]==1: convert[z]=a['X_%d=1'],z
            elif temp[z]==2: convert[z]=a['X_%d=2'],z
            elif temp[z]==3: convert[z]=a['X_%d=3'],z
            else : continue 

        if (r%2==1):
            result1= result1 +reduce(lambda x, y: x*y,convert)
        else : 
            result2= result2 +reduce(lambda x, y: x*y,convert)
        print("Done")
        print()
    print('the total=',result1-result2)
```

Comment: WARNING:  Full_List is a LIST containing LISTS.  Did you wanted that?

Comment: yes. it is part of the solution

Comment: I don't know if you can do that, but please approve my edit.  I added line numbers

Comment: `['X_%d=1']` is not a valid key. Format that string and it will probably fix itself

Comment: i need to insert the value of z in the place of %d

Comment: `[f'X_{z}=1]` and so on. But it still fails because `for z in range(0,5)` and you don't have any X_0=something in a